# If statement to skip division by zero

Tags: awk

I'm trying to skip division by zero in a file that looks like this. For each element in col1 sum the values in col3 and col4 and divide sumcol3/sumcol4.

```
A 3 0.100000 0.200000
A 4 0.100000 0.200000
B 1 0.200000 0.200000
B 5 0.200000 0.000000
C 3 0.200000 0.200000
X 3 0.000000 0.000000
X 5 0.200000 0.200000
D 100 0.00000 0.200000
```

adapting the following code

```
# set fields delimiters 
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

# the first time col1 value occurs, store other cols
!h[$1] {
    h[$1] = ++n  # save ordering
    d[n] = $1 OFS $2
}

# store sums
{
    i = h[$1]  # recover ordering
    a[i] += $3
    b[i] += $4
}

# output cols and the computed values
END {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {if (b[i]!="0.000000") {print d[i], a[i], b[i], a[i]/b[i]}}
}
```

But I'm still getting division by zero

desired output would be

```
A 3 0.200000 0.400000 0.500000 
B 1 0.400000 0.200000 0.200000
C 3 0.200000 0.200000 0.100000
X 3 0.200000 0.200000 0.100000
```

Comment: You are making a comparison of a number with a string. This will always be true. For clarity of your code you should write `b[i] != 0`. You could just write `if(b[i])` but this will make it harder to read your code (in one week you will have forgotten what it means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk, an expression evaluating to zero in an arithmetic context is always seen as `0`<sup>1</sup>. That means, when `b[i]`'s value is zero,

```
b[i] != "0.000000"
```

is the same as:

```
0 != "0.000000"
```

It would be ambiguous if this would evaluate to `true`. So, you should either use `b[i]!=0` or drop `!="0.000000"` completely<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Try running following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 0.0 + 0.000000 + 0}'
```

<sup>2</sup> In awk -and many other scripting/programming languages-, an expression evaluating to a non-zero value evaluates to `true` in a Boolean context. So, `b[i]!=0` and `b[i]` is the same when `b[i]` is holding a numeric value.

Comment: It seems to work. I don't get it. why just saying if (b[i]) works? Thnxs!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it since your samples are not proper Input_file(eg--> $19 is not there). IMHO I would take this approach. I have added a warning statement to get warning in output, you could remove it in case you don't need it.

You could change your `for` loop line to following.

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {printf("%d %d %d %d\n",d[i], a[i], b[i], b[i]!=0?a[i]/b[i]:"Warn: There was an attempt to divide by zero")}
```